# How to access to winform controls from the other thread?

Tags: c#, winforms

For examle, I want to change text in the textBox from the method of the other class. How should I do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110458/winforms-interthread-modification

Answer (score 2):

You can only access WinForm controls from the thread that created them (the same is true in WPF). But there is a mechanism inbuilt to help you: `Invoke`.

See this question for examples: [WinForms interthread modification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110458/winforms-interthread-modification)