# Watching Folder Activity in VB.NET Help me

Tags: vb.net, android-activity, directory

I want to work program Watching Folder Activity
But I am having a problem in the course of the work program
Shows me an error message
Look this picture [ https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApV7k.png ]
This Full source my program :

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Diagnostics
Public Class Form1
    Public watchfolder As FileSystemWatcher
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        watchfolder = New System.IO.FileSystemWatcher()

        'this is the path we want to monitor
        watchfolder.Path = TextBox1.Text

        'Add a list of Filter we want to specify
        'make sure you use OR for each Filter as we need to
        'all of those

        watchfolder.NotifyFilter = IO.NotifyFilters.DirectoryName
        watchfolder.NotifyFilter = watchfolder.NotifyFilter Or _
                                   IO.NotifyFilters.FileName
        watchfolder.NotifyFilter = watchfolder.NotifyFilter Or _
                                   IO.NotifyFilters.Attributes

        ' add the handler to each event
        AddHandler watchfolder.Changed, AddressOf logchange
        AddHandler watchfolder.Created, AddressOf logchange
        AddHandler watchfolder.Deleted, AddressOf logchange

        ' add the rename handler as the signature is different
        AddHandler watchfolder.Renamed, AddressOf logrename

        'Set this property to true to start watching
        '................
        watchfolder.EnableRaisingEvents = True

        Button1.Enabled = False
        Button2.Enabled = True

        'End of code for btn_start_click
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        watchfolder.EnableRaisingEvents = False
        Button1.Enabled = True
        Button2.Enabled = False
    End Sub
    Public Sub logrename(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As  _
                            System.IO.RenamedEventArgs)
        TextBox2.Text &= "File" & e.OldName & _
                      " has been renamed to " & e.Name & vbCrLf
    End Sub
    Private Sub logchange(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As  _
                        System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs)
        If e.ChangeType = IO.WatcherChangeTypes.Changed Then
            TextBox2.Text &= "File " & e.FullPath & _
                                    " has been modified" & vbCrLf
        End If
        If e.ChangeType = IO.WatcherChangeTypes.Created Then
            TextBox2.Text &= "File " & e.FullPath & _
                                     " has been created" & vbCrLf
        End If
        If e.ChangeType = IO.WatcherChangeTypes.Deleted Then
            TextBox2.Text &= "File " & e.FullPath & _
                                    " has been deleted" & vbCrLf
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The events will be called on a separate thread automatically.
You can't change the value of a control created on another thread.
So when you are trying to update the value of TextBox2 created on the main thread, an error appears.
You can use a delegate function and check the control's InvoqueRequired property.
Maybe this could help you : [Automating the InvokeRequired code pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367718/automating-the-invokerequired-code-pattern)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the FileSystemWatcher which is running in a separate thread tries to access a WinForms control. However only the main thread of your application can modify the UI elements. This question should solve the problem: [WinForms interthread modification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110458/winforms-interthread-modification)

Comment: Thank you
Please can you modify my Source ^ even disappear this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This delegates function may solve your problem.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Diagnostics
Public Class Form1
    Public watchfolder As FileSystemWatcher
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        watchfolder = New System.IO.FileSystemWatcher()

        'this is the path we want to monitor
        watchfolder.Path = TextBox1.Text

        'Add a list of Filter we want to specify
        'make sure you use OR for each Filter as we need to
        'all of those

        watchfolder.NotifyFilter = IO.NotifyFilters.DirectoryName
        watchfolder.NotifyFilter = watchfolder.NotifyFilter Or _
                                   IO.NotifyFilters.FileName
        watchfolder.NotifyFilter = watchfolder.NotifyFilter Or _
                                   IO.NotifyFilters.Attributes

        ' add the handler to each event
        AddHandler watchfolder.Changed, AddressOf logchange
        AddHandler watchfolder.Created, AddressOf logchange
        AddHandler watchfolder.Deleted, AddressOf logchange

        ' add the rename handler as the signature is different
        AddHandler watchfolder.Renamed, AddressOf logrename

        'Set this property to true to start watching
        '................
        watchfolder.EnableRaisingEvents = True

        Button1.Enabled = False
        Button2.Enabled = True

        'End of code for btn_start_click
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        watchfolder.EnableRaisingEvents = False
        Button1.Enabled = True
        Button2.Enabled = False
    End Sub
    Public Sub logrename(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As  _
                            System.IO.RenamedEventArgs)
        Invoke(New SetTextDel(AddressOf SetText), "File" & e.OldName & _
                      " has been renamed to " & e.Name & vbCrLf)
    End Sub
    Private Sub logchange(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As  _
                        System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs)
        If e.ChangeType = IO.WatcherChangeTypes.Changed Then
            Invoke(New SetTextDel(AddressOf SetText), "File " & e.FullPath & _
                                    " has been modified" & vbCrLf)
        End If
        If e.ChangeType = IO.WatcherChangeTypes.Created Then
            Invoke(New SetTextDel(AddressOf SetText), "File " & e.FullPath & _
                                     " has been created" & vbCrLf)
        End If
        If e.ChangeType = IO.WatcherChangeTypes.Deleted Then
            Invoke(New SetTextDel(AddressOf SetText), "File " & e.FullPath & _
                                    " has been deleted" & vbCrLf)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Delegate Sub SetTextDel(ByVal msg As String)

    Private Sub SetText(ByVal msg As String)
        TextBox2.Text = msg
    End Sub

End Class
```